# Split a string from numeric points and keep only the points' statements in a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, vuejs2, split

**I have this input-**

```
"\n\nOpen Ended Questions:\n1. What makes Vue a popular choice for web development?\n2. How does Vue compare to other JavaScript frameworks?\n3. What are the advantages of using Vue?\n\nClosed Ended Questions:\n1. Does Vue support server-side rendering?\n2. Is Vue compatible with TypeScript?\n3. Does Vue have a built-in router?"
```

**I want this output-**

```
[
  "What makes Vue a popular choice for web development?",
  "How does Vue compare to other JavaScript frameworks?",
  "What are the advantages of using Vue?",
  "Does Vue support server-side rendering?",
  "Is Vue compatible with TypeScript?",
  "Does Vue have a built-in router?",
]
```

**I tried this-**

```js
let string = "\n\nOpen Ended Questions:\n1. What makes Vue a popular choice for web development?\n2. How does Vue compare to other JavaScript frameworks?\n3. What are the advantages of using Vue?\n\nClosed Ended Questions:\n1. Does Vue support server-side rendering?\n2. Is Vue compatible with TypeScript?\n3. Does Vue have a built-in router?"

// First, remove all line breaks and two strings
string = string.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "").replace('Open Ended Questions:', '').replace('Closed Ended Questions:', '');

// Split the string from this format, "<integer><dot><space>"
let result = string.split(/(\d+)\.\ /);

// Filter the only items which are not empty and not a number
result = result.filter(item => item && isNaN(item));

// Final result
console.log(result);
```

**Code explanation-**.

1. Firstly, I removed all line breaks and some non-required strings.
2. Secondly, I split the string from this format `<integer><dot><space>`, i.e. `"1. ", "2. "`, etc.
3. At last, filtered only the numeric points' statements in a separate array.

The solution is working fine but I am not sure if its the right way to do this, because of this hardcoded removal operation- `replace('Open Ended Questions:', '').replace('Closed Ended Questions:', '')`

Can anyone please suggest a better/non-complex/correct way to do this?

Comment: I would first split by line breaks and then process each question. The way you are doing it may bug out if one of those questions contains a substring of the form `<integer><dot><space>` (for example, referencing a previous question).

Comment: Sounds good enough, I don't think that you can optimize it that much from a performance/readability approach anyway. Keep it as is, totally fine!

Comment: Thanks, @Fractalism. Your point is correct, my solution would not work in that substring case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate the lines from the input and if a line matches `/^\d+\.\s+` (that is, digits-dot-spaces), put the rest of the line in the array:

```js
input = "\n\nOpen Ended Questions:\n1. What makes Vue a popular choice for web development?\n2. How does Vue compare to other JavaScript frameworks?\n3. What are the advantages of using Vue?\n\nClosed Ended Questions:\n1. Does Vue support server-side rendering?\n2. Is Vue compatible with TypeScript?\n3. Does Vue have a built-in router?"

output = []

for (let line of input.split('\n')) {
  line = line.trim()
  let m = line.match(/^\d+\.\s+(.+)/)
  if (m)
    output.push(m[1])
}

console.log(output)
```

You can also do that with one single regular expression, but this would be less readable IMO:

```js
input = "\n\nOpen Ended Questions:\n1. What makes Vue a popular choice for web development?\n2. How does Vue compare to other JavaScript frameworks?\n3. What are the advantages of using Vue?\n\nClosed Ended Questions:\n1. Does Vue support server-side rendering?\n2. Is Vue compatible with TypeScript?\n3. Does Vue have a built-in router?"

output = [...input.matchAll(/^\d+\.\s+(.+)/gm)].map(r => r[1])

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Split into lines
2. Filter the lines
3. Map the lines (removing the enumerator)

```js
const input = "\n\nOpen Ended Questions:\n1. What makes Vue a popular choice for web development?\n2. How does Vue compare to other JavaScript frameworks?\n3. What are the advantages of using Vue?\n\nClosed Ended Questions:\n1. Does Vue support server-side rendering?\n2. Is Vue compatible with TypeScript?\n3. Does Vue have a built-in router?"

const lines = input.split('\n');
const listItems = lines
  .filter((line) => /^\d+\./.test(line))
  .map((line) => line.replace(/^\d+\./, "").trim());

console.log(listItems);
```

Comment: Some suggestions:
1. `(\d+)` doesn't need the parenthesis (though if it's there for readability, then it's fine)
2. `.` should be `\.` to match the literal dot character
3. The space character could be replace with `\s+` to match multiple consecutive spaces

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming each question ends with `?` and starts with new line `\n` as per the input string you mentioned. In consideration of above pattern, Here is the work around solution to achieve the required output.

```js
// Input string
const str = "\n\nOpen Ended Questions:\n1. What makes Vue a popular choice for web development?\n2. How does Vue compare to other JavaScript frameworks?\n3. What are the advantages of using Vue?\n\nClosed Ended Questions:\n1. Does Vue support server-side rendering?\n2. Is Vue compatible with TypeScript?\n3. Does Vue have a built-in router?";

// Splitted the input string based on the new line character '\n'
const splittedStr = str.split("\n");

// Filtered out the array items which ends with question mark (?)
const questionsArr = splittedStr.filter(str => str.endsWith('?'));

// Finally removing the numbers from the starting of the question texts.
const res = questionsArr.map(str => str.replace(/^[\d]+\.\ /, ''));

// Desired output
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using positive lookbehind `(?<=)` and lookahead `(?=)`:

```js
const str = "\n\nOpen Ended Questions:\n1. What makes Vue a popular choice for web development?\n2. How does Vue compare to other JavaScript frameworks?\n3. What are the advantages of using Vue?\n\nClosed Ended Questions:\n1. Does Vue support server-side rendering?\n2. Is Vue compatible with TypeScript?\n3. Does Vue have a built-in router?";

const items = str.match(/(?<=^\d+\. +).+?(?=\n|$)/gm)
console.log(items);
```

Explanation on: [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xbQ5do/1)

- lookbehind: `(?<=\n\d+\. +)` Start of string, one or more digits, dot, one or more spaces
- non-greedy match `.+?` any character one or more times as few as possible
- lookahead: `(?=\n|$)` newline or end of line

### Without lookbehind assertions

use this simplified Regex, that basically matches a Start-of-line `^` having the *Digit/s followed by a dot and space* pattern and captures the remaining string `(.+)` till the End-of-line `$` (with Global and Multiline flags `gm`)

```
/^\d\. (.+)$/gm
```

[Regex101.com demo and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/9wV0qO/1)

To support WebKit-based browsers like i.e: **Safari**, that do not support the Lookbehind assertion, you could use [String.prototype.matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) to get an iterator with the matched groups. Use the Spread Syntax `...` to get a 2D array and access the first matching group using `match[1]` and convert it to Array using [Array.ptototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const str = "\n\nOpen Ended Questions:\n1. What makes Vue a popular choice for web development?\n2. How does Vue compare to other JavaScript frameworks?\n3. What are the advantages of using Vue?\n\nClosed Ended Questions:\n1. Does Vue support server-side rendering?\n2. Is Vue compatible with TypeScript?\n3. Does Vue have a built-in router?";

const items = [...str.matchAll(/^\d\. (.+)$/gm)].map(m => m[1]);
console.log(items);
```

To additionally support ancient **Internet Explorer** browsers that do not support the String.prototype.matchAll() method, use `.exec()` like:

```js
const str = "\n\nOpen Ended Questions:\n1. What makes Vue a popular choice for web development?\n2. How does Vue compare to other JavaScript frameworks?\n3. What are the advantages of using Vue?\n\nClosed Ended Questions:\n1. Does Vue support server-side rendering?\n2. Is Vue compatible with TypeScript?\n3. Does Vue have a built-in router?";

const reg = /^\d\. (.+)$/gm;
const res = [];
let m;
while(m = reg.exec(str)) res.push(m[1]);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Roko, this is the simplest solution. The only problem is, I read about these operators and found that `lookbehind` operator is not supported in non-V8 browsers, such as Safari, and Internet Explorer, and this answer is also not working in Safari. Do you have any thoughts about it?

Answer (score 0):

1. In case you split with new line you will get

   ```
   part  0: 
   part  1: 
   part  2: Open Ended Questions:
   part  3: 1. What makes Vue a popular choice for web development? 
   part  4: 2. How does Vue compare to other JavaScript frameworks?
   part  5: 3. What are the advantages of using Vue?
   part  6: 
   part  7: Closed Ended Questions:
   part  8: 1. Does Vue support server-side rendering?
   part  9: 2. Is Vue compatible with TypeScript?
   part 10: 3. Does Vue have a built-in router?
   ```
2. Then you can filter empty and irrelevant rows.
3. Then remove numbers at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your input and if the question have always the same structure?
If yes you have to define a regex that matches your questions format and from there you don't need to replace anything the sentences with empty strings:

```js
let string = "\n\nOpen Ended Questions:\n1. What makes Vue a popular choice for web development?\n2. How does Vue compare to other JavaScript frameworks?\n3. What are the advantages of using Vue?\n\nClosed Ended Questions:\n1. Does Vue support server-side rendering?\n2. Is Vue compatible with TypeScript?\n3. Does Vue have a built-in router?"
// ([0-9])+ is the question number and it has to be 1 or more than one character
// \. is the dot after question number
// .+ is your question
// (\?)? the first question mark after the question text
let regexp = /([0-9])+\..+(\?)?/g;
var questions = string.match(regexp);
var result = [];
questions.forEach((l) => result.push(l.replace(/([0-9])+\./g,'').trim()));
console.log(result);
```